# How do I download binary file in dotnet Maui mobile app?

Tags: c#, android, .net-core, maui, dotnet-httpclient

I have a rest endpoint that returns a sqlite database file for my Android app. If I create an empty Sqlite db in the app. The initial load of the db from my web api takes to long. In the past I've had a seed db in the assets. But the data gets old and then I'm back to the same issue of the initial refresh of the data on a new install takes to long. So my api endpoint creates a fresh initial db for download and I want to install it into my application data directory on initial start up.

I have an APIService class for all my rest calls.
Here is my code:

```
  public async Task<bool> GetInitialDatabaseSeed ()
  {
       Uri requetUrl = new Uri( host + "/data/download");

       try
       {               
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/octet-stream");
       var response = await client.GetStreamAsync(requetUrl).ConfigureAwait(false);

         if (response != null)
         {
            // save file to download area. 
           string fullfileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "access.db3");
  
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                 response.CopyTo(ms);
                 ms.Position = 0;
                 byte[] file = ms.ToArray();                        
                 await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(fullfileName, file);
            }
            response.Dispose();
            return true;

        }
        return false;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          Debug.WriteLine("ERROR on loading of db3: " + ex.Message);
          return false;
      }           
                      
 }
```

I get a good response from the call. But the application just hangs on the response.CopyTo(ms). I've tried CopyToAsync() same result. I've tried client.GetAsync(), but that hangs on the getAsync() call. I've tried client.GetByteArrayAsync(), but the call also hangs.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Why do you use an intermediate memory stream? Do away with it. Write the response directly to file.

Comment: My bet is this code runs in background and fails to show on main thread the UI requesting permissions to write to disk. Try request permissions first on UI thread then run this code.

Comment: About httpclient, you can refer to the official doc: [Retrieve data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/rest#retrieve-data).